# jQuery animated content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I once visited a personal site which used a nice jQuery animation. Using the scrollbar the plugin showed different information, almost like a letter but without following a linear sequence. Something like this: [image: Example]

Of course, only one square (div) was at the screen at the time.

Do you know what plugin does that? I need to do something similar ando would be very helpful. I tried searching for about one hour but I think I don't know how is that kind of animation called, so I didn't find anything useful, just scrolling effects like "Go to top" or plugins animating the "go to anchor" functionality.

Do anyone of you have ever seen the plugin I'm talking about?

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you are talking about. I guess you do not have the link to the website that you are talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I regret I didn't save it in my bookmarks. Let's suppose in the square 1 I have my introduction, it's what it's visible when you load the page. Then you use the scroll (or te arrow keys) and it animates the "path" to the second square, let's suppose it's the "about me".

And so forth, until all the squares showed. Did you understand it now? I'm really sorry, it's kinda difficult to explain it, I guess that's why I didn't have any luck with the search engines.

Comment: Or like this? http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Comment: Yes! Not exactly what I was talking about but it's really close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery Scroll Path](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath). The demo is [here](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/).

Comment: As I said in the comments, it's really really close. I think I can modify it if the license allows me to.

Accepted as answer, I'm really thankful!